# JSON input filtering needed or not

Tags: php, mysql, json

This could be a stupid question but I'm rather confused. I'm getting JSON files from users and json_decode within PHP and put into MySql. Is filtering/escaping the decoded data against SQL injections needed or unnecessary when inserting into db? or alternatively something else should be done?

Answer (score 4):

It is absolutely needed. Never trust data coming from your users.

Comment: json can be broken. do you have any idea how can i do this?

Comment: Decode the json with PHP. Then sanitize the data. Then insert into database as needed. I recommend using a library or framework ( that escapes SQL ) to handle database insertions to mitigate risk of injection.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_real_escape_string()` on the data going in, then the db won't suffer an injection attack. However, that doesn't fix a json issue. You'd have to run a separate validation for that.

Comment: i know that function but as we both said there will be a json issue. point is how can we solve this...

Comment: I think you may need to post again to ask about actual json. There isn't a question above about json. I was answering the part of your post with a question mark: `"Is filtering/escaping the decoded data against *SQL injections* needed or unnecessary when inserting into db?"` (emphasis added)